# max(sum) group by in sql

Tags: sql, sum, max

I have the following table:
[Table][image: 1]

I need to output such a result, which will show games where there were more turnovers, but at the same time Winner = 1.

I started from this:

```
select 
game_id
, team_id
, sum(turnovers) as summ
, winner as summ 
from testik
group by 
game_id
, team_id
, winner
```

And it gave me this:
[Result Table]

[image: 2]

How can I show games which meets my condition?

Comment: More turnovers compared to what?

Comment: Could you add the database version you are using?

Comment: whats your desired output , show that as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your Query is just missing the where clause to select games and teams only having "true" in winner column:

```
  select 
game_id
, team_id
, sum(turnovers) as summ
, winner as summ 
from testik where winner='true'
group by 
game_id
, team_id
, winner
```

**result:**

[image]

or if you want the result with max(turnovers) instead of sum(turnovers) use below query:

```
select 
game_id
, team_id
, max(turnovers)as summ
, winner as summ 
from testik where winner='true'
group by 
game_id
, team_id
, winner
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly here is what you want to do, if not please provide sample output.

the query below shows which game_id has the most turnover for winner teams:

```
select 
   game_id
   , sum(turnovers) as summ
from testik
where 
   winner = true
group by 
   game_id
order by 
   sum(turnovers) desc
```